# Checking args with new main function syntax

Tags: scala, program-entry-point, scala-3

When using new main function syntax:

`@main def prog(nb: Int, stuff: String) = ...`

vs old one :

`def main(args: Array[String]) = ...`

Is it possible to check the number of arguments passed on the command line?
Something we can do with a test on args.length in old syntax.

I would like to produce a customized syntax error instead of "Illegal command line: more arguments expected".

Answer (score 1):

As demonstrated [here](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/main-functions.html), the final argument of the method attached to `@main` should be type `String*` (or, I suppose, any other vararg type) if you want to allow for a variable number of arguments on the command line.

```
@main def prog(c:Char, n:Int, rest:String*) =
   println(s"$c:$n and ${rest.length} other args")
```